# Electromagnetic Field vs Electromagnetic Waves

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Currently new to Electromagnetism field , I have a few questions to clear up my confusions :

• Electromagnetic Waves range from Radio Waves up to Gamma Waves how are those created ? I understand that a moving charge creates an electromagnetic field but how does this field radiate the electromagnetic waves?

• Transformers essentially work using Electromagnetic Induction and hence there is an electromagnetic field in transformers operation : Does this mean that a transformer emits electromagnetic waves? Or is the field just static in the region and hence no waves are emitted ? What would be the type of waves produced by a transformer if any are emitted ?

Thanks Ahead

Comment: You say you are just starting.  If you continue your studies, these questions will be answered.  Be patient.   It's out of scope for us here to provide your foundation education!

Comment: Yes, a transformer induces an EM field around itself (and technically it's effects occur up to any distance away), but they are incredibly weak even a small distance away and it wouldn't typically be considered a source of "radiation". A light bulb is a better electromagnetic radiator than a transformer, because electromagnetic radiation is the job of a light bulb.

Comment: A transformer has a time-varying electromagnetic field. However, only if this field is periodic in time and rather far away from the source (here the transformer) it would be considered as radiation.